# What is the correct way to manage AWS accounts when the different users are paying?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Here's the scenario:

- I have an AWS account for developing personal projects.
- As a freelance developer, I frequently need to develop an app for a client that runs on AWS (and of course I need full access to it), but my client should be billed for it's usage (not me).

What is the correct approach to achieve this?

My clients should be the owners of their project's account, and create an user for me with full access? Or is is possible to manage the applications from my account but setting different billing information for each one?

Hope you can help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well Your customers can grant access to theirs accounts with help of IAM. The can create IAM user with limited access, and when you en the contract they can revoke access.

Comment: @monsieurBelbo: You can also use AWS's consolidated billing feature.  This would let you have your own account, but a parent account would be responsible for its bill.

Answer (score 0):

The same is here.
My boss pays for the service but the manager is me. He granted the access and I have the complete freedom of doing things.